# Sound and complete algorithms for boolean satifiability

Tags: satisfiability, 3-sat, sat-solvers

To my best knowledge, these are the sound and complete algorithms for boolean satisfiability

- Variations of DPLL algorithm (e.g. CDCL, Look-ahead solvers)
- Stalmarks method
- Binary Decision Diagram (BDD)

I am looking for other sound and complete algorithms for boolean satisfiability?

Comment: If you don't care about efficiency, then simple algorithms like brute force enumeration also fit the bill.

Comment: Take a look at Skiena's discussion of this. He describes a few options if I recall correctly.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta: Can you post the link? I googled it, but didn't find.

Comment: I was thinking about his book, *The Algorithm Design Manual* but he also has a [website](http://www.algorist.com/).

Answer (score 2):

[Resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) is sound and complete. In recursive learning, you recursively evaluate the clause satisfiability requirements for identifying common assignments. Look at say page 29 and onwards in [these slides](http://logos.ucd.ie/events/sac10/sac10-tutorial-part1.pdf).

Comment: Resolution is the non-deterministic version of DPLL.